# android array list null

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm designing an Android app that downloads information from a website and prints a list on-screen with that information in the form of an Array List.

However, the ArrayList I use doesn't load correctly and my screen becomes blank.

Activity code:

**Tenda.java**

```
public class Tenda extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, LocationListener {

    ProgressDialog lDialog;
    String json_string;
    SuperAdapter adapter_super;
    int user_id;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public String provider;
    private String  lattitude , longitude; 

    /*************************************************/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tenda);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        init_conf();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tenda, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_update:
                updateList();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                alert_search();
                return true;   
            case R.id.menu_cancel:
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

        TextView stock = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_stock);
        int num_stock = Integer.parseInt(stock.getText().toString()) ; 

        if(num_stock!=0){
            ArrayList<Super> productes=adapter_super.getItems_producte();
            Super current_product= productes.get(position);

            alert_buy(num_stock,current_product);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "OUT OF STOCK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void init_conf(){

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        user_id = extras.getInt("user_id");

        Toast.makeText(this, "user id"+Integer.toString(user_id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ListView lsv_producto = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_productes);
        adapter_super = new SuperAdapter(Tenda.this,null);
        lsv_producto.setAdapter(adapter_super);
        lsv_producto.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        updateList();

    }

    private void updateList(){
        loading();
        String url = "http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/products.php?user_id="+user_id;

        boolean is_con=is_connected();

        if(is_con){
            Log.i("Connection", "true");
            AsyncTask(url);
            Toast.makeText(this, "connected internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            json_string=storeRead();
            refreshListByJson(json_string);
            Toast.makeText(this, "not connected internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void search(String text){
        loading();
        String url="http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/search.php?user_id="+user_id+"&q="+text;

        boolean is_con=is_connected();
        if(is_con){
            Log.i("search URL", url);
            Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            searchAsyncTask(url);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

private void buy(Super producte, int value){

        int product_id=  producte.getId();

        String url="http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/buy.php?user_id="+user_id+
                    "&product_id="+product_id+
                    "&items="+value+
                    "&lat="+1+
                    "&long="+1;

        Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void AsyncTask(String url){
        LongAsyncTask task = new LongAsyncTask();
        task.execute(url);
    }

    private void searchAsyncTask(String url){
        SearchAsyncTask task = new SearchAsyncTask();
        task.execute(url);
    }

    public void alert_search(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), m_Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                search(m_Text);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    public void alert_buy(int max_value,final Super producte){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("BUY");

        final NumberPicker number= new NumberPicker(this);
        number.setMaxValue(max_value);
        number.setMinValue(0);
        builder.setView(number);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int value= number.getValue();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                buy(producte,value);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    /*************************ASYNC TASK************************/

    public class LongAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("DO IN BACKGROUND", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }
       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           storeWrite(json_string);
           refreshListByJson(json_string);//line 257
       }

    }

        public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("Search result", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }

       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE SEARCH", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           refreshListByJson(json_string);
       }

    }

    public class BuyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("buy result", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }
       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE SEARCH", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

    }

    /*************************************************/

    private void refreshListByJson(String json){//line 300
        lDialog.dismiss();
       Store store=Store.newStore(json);
       if (store.getProductes() != null)
       {
           Log.i("store-nom", "" + store.getStore());//line 305
           Log.i("store-producte", "" + store.getProductes().toString()); //line 306
           adapter_super.setItems_producte(store.getProductes());    
       }
    }

    private void storeWrite(String data){
        String FILENAME = "json_store";

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Write STORAGE", data);

    }

    private String storeRead(){
        String FILENAME = "json_store";

        FileInputStream  fis;
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            fis= openFileInput (FILENAME);
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                fileContent.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.i("READ STORAGE", fileContent.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileContent.toString();
    }

    public String conect(String url_string){

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        BufferedReader reader= null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(url_string);
            con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line ="";
            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                responseBuffer.append(line);
            }

            return responseBuffer.toString(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage(),ex);
            return  null;
        }

    }

    public boolean is_connected(){
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (i == null)
            return false;
          if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
          if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
          return true;
    }

    private void loading(){
         lDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         lDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
         lDialog.setCancelable(false);
         lDialog.show();
    }


/*** Location ***/

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int lat = (int) (arg0.getLatitude());
int lng = (int) (arg0.getLongitude());
lattitude = "Lattitude: "+ lat ;
longitude = "Longitude: "+ lng; 
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
////TODO Auto-generated method stub

}               

}
```

**Store.java**

```
    public class Store {

    private String store;
    private ArrayList<Super> productes;

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }
    public void setSuper(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    public ArrayList<Super> getProductes() {
        return productes;
    }
    public void setProductes(ArrayList<Super> productes) {
        this.productes = productes;
    }

    static Store newStore(String json_string){

        Gson gson= new Gson();

        Store store = gson.fromJson(json_string,Store.class);

        return store;

    }


}


    }
```

**Super.java**

```
public class Super {

    private int id;
    private String fabricant;
    private String nom;
    private float preu;
    private int stock;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFabricant() {
        return fabricant;
    }
    public void setFabricant(String fabricant) {
        this.fabricant = fabricant;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public float getPreu() {
        return preu;
    }
    public void setPreu(float preu) {
        this.preu = preu;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

}
```

**LongAsyncTask.java**

```
public class LongAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        return null;
    }


   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   }

}
```

**SuperAdapter.java**

```
public class SuperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public ArrayList<Super> getItems_producte() {
        return items_producte;
    }

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Super> items_producte;

    public SuperAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Super> items_producte){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items_producte= items_producte;
    }

        @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(items_producte==null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return items_producte.size();
        }   }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items_producte.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup Parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = contentView;

        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflate =(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.info_product, null,false);
        }

        Super item_producte = items_producte.get(position);

        TextView id = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_id);
        TextView fabricant = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_fabricant);
        TextView nom = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_nom);
        TextView preu = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_preu);
        TextView stock = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_stock);

        id.setText(Integer.toString(item_producte.getId()));
        fabricant.setText(item_producte.getFabricant());
        nom.setText(item_producte.getNom());
        preu.setText(Float.toString(item_producte.getPreu()));
        stock.setText(Integer.toString(item_producte.getStock()));

        fabricant.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        nom.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        preu.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        stock.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));

        if(position%2==0){
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.files_parelles));

        }
        else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.files_imparelles));
        }

        /*STOCK COLOR*/
        if(item_producte.getStock()<=0){
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_bg));

            fabricant.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            nom.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            preu.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            stock.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));

        }


        return view;
    }


    public void setItems_producte(ArrayList<Super> items_producte) {
        this.items_producte = items_producte;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

The main problem is located in this section:

```
private void refreshListByJson(String json){//line 300
        lDialog.dismiss();
       Store store=Store.newStore(json);
       if (store.getProductes() != null)
       {
         Log.i("store-nom", "" + store.getStore());//line 305
        Log.i("store-producte", "" + store.getProductes().toString()); //line 306
           adapter_super.setItems_producte(store.getProductes());    
       }
    }
```

The "if" condition is not fulfilled: store.getProductes() is null.

It's strange because the app can DL the info from internet and I can see that in the logcat output: for some reason it doesn't load into the ArrayList.

Could you please help me in figuring out what I must do for the ArrayList to work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To all who replied: I haven't made any comments yet because I've been struggling to make my emulator work and until it works I can't test how these suggested changes will affect my app. Once I have been able to test them I will reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ListView lsv_producto = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_productes);
    adapter_super = new SuperAdapter(Tenda.this,null);
    lsv_producto.setAdapter(adapter_super);
```

You are passing null in SuperAdapter cnstructer, you need to pass ArrrayList instead of passing null.

Comment: When I try to write "ArrayList<Super> productes" it doesn't recognize it as a variable. I understand what you mean but I don't see how to implement it.

Comment: Can you please check my new answer posted (about 44 mins ago)

Answer (score 1):

Put condition this way

```
if (store.getProductes() != null && store.getProductes().size()>0){
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change anything. It prevents the app from crashing out of NullPointerException but the ArrayList doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

```
private ArrayList<Super> productes = new ArrayList<Super>():
```

You never use your setProducts too so this will be empty.

Comment: Despit this, the ArrayList continues to be on blank. Any ideas? The information from Internet is successfully DLed.

Comment: problem may be with your parser. But I never use Gson lib. I have worked with org.json android default.

Answer (score 1):

First Remove the below code

```
ListView lsv_producto = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_productes);
adapter_super = new SuperAdapter(Tenda.this,null);
lsv_producto.setAdapter(adapter_super);
```

Now modified the refreshListByJson() as below

```
private void refreshListByJson(String json){//line 300
    lDialog.dismiss();
   Store store=Store.newStore(json);
   if (store.getProductes() != null)
   {
     Log.i("store-nom", "" + store.getStore());//line 305
    Log.i("store-producte", "" + store.getProductes().toString()); //line 306
       adapter_super.setItems_producte(store.getProductes());    
   }

   //////////////////
   ListView lsv_producto = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_productes);
      adapter_super = new SuperAdapter(Tenda.this,store.getProductes());
      lsv_producto.setAdapter(adapter_super);
  ////////////////////


}
```

Comment: I've tried this as you said but the screen remains in blank nevertheless.